# filling color into d3 world map (choropleth map)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

How should I write the **attr** fill function in D3, in order to color the map according to the rate of urbanization inside the map JSON API?

**e.g:** this is the api for Afghanistan

> {"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.03600360036003601,0.017366249624962495],"translate":[-180,-90]},"objects":{"countries":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4,5]],"id":"Afghanistan"
>   ,"rate":3.96}

if I write:

```
svg.selectAll('path.land')
     .data( topojson.feature(
      worldJson, worldJson.objects.countries).features )
     .enter().append ('path')
     .attr ('class', 'land')
     .attr ('d', path)
     .attr ("fill", (d,i)=>{      
        const countries = d.id;

        if(countries == "Afghanistan")
        {  
          return  "blue";
        }
        else {return "grey";}})
```

Afghanistan will turn blue, however if I write:

```
    svg.selectAll('path.land')
     .data( topojson.feature(
      worldJson, worldJson.objects.countries).features )
     .enter().append ('path')
     .attr ('class', 'land')
     .attr ('d', path)
     .attr ("fill", (d,i)=>{      
        const urban = d.rate;

        if(urban == 3.96)
        {  
          return  "blue";
        }
        else {return "grey";}})
```

Afghanistan will not turn blue. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topojson ignores the `rate` attribute.
To add custom data, you have to use the `properties` attribute like in the following example:

```
var worldJson = {"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.03600360036003601,0.017366249624962495],"translate":[-180,-90]},"objects":{"countries":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"id":"Afghanistan" ,"properties":{"rate":3.96}}]}},"arcs":[[[7080,6666],[-5,5],[-10,-13]]]}
```

Then you can use it this way: `const urban = d.properties.rate;`.

You can try it on this Runkit https://runkit.com/dmnized/5b695446f8311b00125e4494.